# Linux Error: 29: Illegal seek in LSNRCTL for Linux Version 11.2

Tags: linux, oracle

I'm trying to get Oracle Database 11g Express set up on my server so that it is accessible from the outside.  I can talk to the DB locally using SQLPlus, so the database is definitely running.  I think my issue is with the listener.

Here's what I'm getting:

```
$ lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 27-AUG-2012 16:14:38

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNS-12537: TNS:connection closed
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00507: Connection closed
   Linux Error: 29: Illegal seek
```

I've tried two solutions I found online, and neither seemed to work.  The first, from [dba-oracle.com](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_linux_error_29_illegal_seek.htm), suggests changing `tcp.validcode_checking=yes` to `tcp.validnode_checking=no` in `sqlnet.ora`.  There was no such line, so I added it, and no luck.  My `sqlnet.ora` is otherwise unchanged from when I installed.  Note that this referred to version 10.2.

The second suggested adding `127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost` to `/etc/hosts`, which I did, again with no change.  No processes are listening on port 1521 (`netstat -aopn | grep 1521` returns nothing).

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

## Update

It seems I misunderstood what I was looking at.  The `sqlnet.ora` file is in the `samples` directory, so it's not actually being read by the listener.  Instead it is using the `listener.ora` file, which looks like this:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

The `tnsnames.ora` file looks like this:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

These are again the files that came with the application.  Is there something I need to change here?

Comment: Start with a basic tnsnmaes.ora file and remove your sqlnet.ora file (make a backup before deleting it).

Comment: What Linux  distribution (edit your post with `lsb_release -a` output)? Are you running `lsnrctl start` as the oracle user? Can you edit your question with your full `/etc/hosts` file and the output of `ifconfig -a`? If you move your current `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora` files to a temporary directory and try starting the listener again with `lsnrctl start`, the listener should still start - if it doesn't we know it's an installation problem & not an Oracle config problem

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same problem, searched a lot and tried about everything suggested (like setting /etc/hosts correctly).

In my case (OEL6, 11gR2 XE) it was solved with the following:

`export LD_BIND_NOW=1`

Comment: I got this error trying to set the trace level to 16 (support).  This solution was the only way I could turn on tracing at the level required by support.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is pretty old, but I also hit upon the same issue. This can be resolved by adding below line in /etc/hosts.

127.0.0.1         localhost.localdomain       localhost

I had removed this line accidently, therefore, I was getting the error while starting the listener after the installation of the DB. Also, the listener was not created automatically and I had to add the listener.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported to be a `tnsnames.ora` file issue. Split the files into different ora files and try with each of them. Clean up the file and retype it either using simple Text editor or tools like Toad or SQL Developer.

Comment: I edited my question with tnsnames.ora contents and a better idea of what's going on.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and nothing of the above helped. In my case it was just an invalid domain (= no domain). Once I changed from localhost to localhost.localdomain (in /etc/hostname and sysconfig) everything worked fine.